Function to find prime factors overwrites parts of its results
I'm trying to make an algorithm that shows what primes factors a number is made of. I have made the following code (not optimized) which divides a number into the 2 numbers it's made of. Then I do this until I find what base numbers (primes) those numbers are made from. I have the problem, that I keep resetting the final list, and I don't want to use a global variable.
Any idea how to do this correctly?
The expected output of the following code should be [2, 2, 5, 7], since 4 × 35 = 140, 2 × 2 = 4 and 5 × 7 = 35.
def is_prime(n:int) -> bool: 
    if n==2 or n==3: 
        return True
    for i in range(3, n//2+1): 
        if n%i==0: 
            return False
    return True

def made_of(n:int) -> list[int]: 
    v = []
    for i in range(2, n//2+1): 
        for j in range(2, n//2+1): 
            if i*j==n: 
                v += [i]
                v += [j]
                return v

def is_prime_list(v:list[int]) -> bool: 
    for i in range(0, len(v)): 
        if is_prime(v[i])!= True: 
            return False
    return True

def made_of_prime(v:list[int]) -> list[int]: 
    p = []
    w = []
    if is_prime_list(v)==False: 
        for i in range(0, len(v)): 
            if is_prime(v[i])==True:
                w += [v[i]]
            else: 
                p += made_of(v[i])
                return made_of_prime(p)
    else: 
        w += v
        return w
    return w


if __name__=="__main__": 
    print(made_of_prime(made_of(140)))


@Friedrich oh my. I didn't think about that at all. Stupid mistake, sorry

It might help readers to understand your question if you told us which variable "the final list" is. There are several one-letter variables there and it's a bit cumbersome figuring out which variable you're talking about. Make it easy for people to read your code and help you.

It would also help if you show the expected output for the input value of 140

Your code is close to being complete. It just contains two bugs.
The first is that is is_prime(n) returns True for some non-prime numbers. Specifically, four.
>>> is_prime(4)
True

The fix for this is simple, make sure you check if four is divisible by two.
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n in [2, 3]:
        return True
    for i in range(2, n//2+1):
    #              ^-- Now two, instead of three
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

The next issue is that when you factor non-prime numbers, you forget other numbers in your input list.
def made_of_prime(v:list[int]) -> list[int]: 
    p = []
    w = []
    if is_prime_list(v)==False: 
        for i in range(0, len(v)): 
            if is_prime(v[i])==True:
                w += [v[i]]
            else: 
                p += made_of(v[i])
                return made_of_prime(p) # BUG!

First, what happens to any previous prime numbers in the list? If the input list was [2, 6], then 2 is appended to w, but when you return return made_of_prime(p) the primes in w are lost.
Secondly, what happens to any of the numbers that appear in the input list after v[i]. If the input list was [4, 6], then you end up returning made_of_prime(made_of(4)) and you lose the number 6.
The simple change is not return early, but to separate out the primes and non-primes. And then return the primes plus the factors of the non-primes.
eg.
def made_of_prime(v:list[int]) -> list[int]:
    primes = []
    factors = []
    if is_prime_list(v)==False:
        for i in range(0, len(v)):
            if is_prime(v[i])==True:
                # collect all the primes in the list
                primes += [v[i]]
            else:
                # collect factors of the non-primes in the list
                factors += made_of(v[i])
    else:
        # v only consists of primes
        primes = v
    if factors:
        # if there were non-primes in the list, ensure their factors are prime
        primes += made_of_prime(factors)
    return primes

There are still plenty of optimisations and other things you can do to improve your code, but those were the two bugs in a program that is otherwise sound.

Thank you so much for the help. Im glad I at least was close to the "correct" code.

To avoid resetting the final list and to eliminate the need for a global variable, you can use a recursive approach that passes the current results as an argument to the recursive calls.
Can try this code:
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
  if n < 2:
      return False
  if n == 2:
      return True
  if n % 2 == 0:
      return False
  for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):  # Check up to the square root of n, skipping even numbers
      if n % i == 0:
          return False
  return True


def prime_factors(n: int, factors=None) -> list[int]:
  if factors is None:
      factors = []

  for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):  # Check up to the square root of n
      if n % i == 0:
          # Found a factor, recurse for both i and n // I
          prime_factors(i, factors)
          prime_factors(n // i, factors)
          return factors  # Return early after breaking into factors

  # If no factors are found, n itself is a prime
  factors.append(n)
  return factors


if __name__ == "__main__":
  num = 140
  result = prime_factors(num)
  print(f"The prime factors of {num} are: {sorted(result)}")


Nicely done. You might want to elaborate on some of your choices, though. It might not be obvious to a reader why you only check up to the square root of n. How values are returned from your recursive calls to prime_factors() could also benefit from an explanation.

Turns out your code works with some small tweaks.
I simplified your function made_of_prime() to append the primes obtained by
the recursive call to the known list of prime factors.
Since we only ever let primes into w, we don't need to check for it.
This obviated the need for function is_prime_list() and I removed it.
Turns out your mistrust of your own code's results is to blame.
Furthermore, I took the liberty of applying some formatting and making minimal changes here
and there.
Most of them were suggested by running pylint on your code.
Take a look at the following, slightly modified version of your code:
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n in [2, 3]:
        return True
    for i in range(3, n//2+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def made_of(n: int) -> list[int]:
    for i in range(2, n//2+1):
        for j in range(2, n//2+1):
            if i * j == n:
                return [i, j]
    return []


def made_of_prime(v: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    w = []
    for i in v:
        if is_prime(i):
            w += [i]
        else:
            p = made_of(i)
            w += made_of_prime(p)
    return w


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(made_of_prime(made_of(140)))

# output: [2, 2, 5, 7]

Having said that, I agree with you that the code is "not optimized".
Future readers should note that this is explorative code and far from a
reference implementation to find prime factors.
Most of this code could be rewritten to be more performant.
A guard to prevent negative input should also be put in place.
How to optimize further is beyond the scope of an answer.
More than one book was written on the subject of finding primes.
